# Running VBScript file using another file

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am trying to connect two different files to run by clicking on one. For instance, I want oven.xls excel file to open in the background when I click on test.rcp. Then when i click on test2.rcp, it closes oven.xls and opens oven2.xls. Is this possible using vbscript, or any other method for that matter? Any input would be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what a "rcp" file is, but here are two `vbs` files that do what you need.

```
' test.vbs
With CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    .Visible = True
    .Workbooks.Open "oven.xls"
End With

' test2.vbs
Set e = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

If Not e Is Nothing Then
    e.Workbooks.Close
    e.Workbooks.Open "oven2.xls"
End If
```

Comment: .rcp is a file type we use here. it's a separate file that would also need to be opened. so, the test.rcp file would open along with oven.xls file. So if i open the test.rcp file would the oven.xls file open as well?